# How to add optional properties to my custom made Javascript Interface?

Tags: javascript, object, interface

I am finding a way to somehow use the **Interfaces** of TypeScript in pure JavaScript, and that's the reason why I made **JSInterface**. It's code is given below :

```
function JSInterface() {

  var required = {}

   function _escape(obj) {
     return new Function(' "use strict"; return (' + obj + ')')()
   }

  function _isEqual(x, y) {
     return (x && y && typeof x === 'object' && typeof y === 'object') ?
(Object.keys(x).length === Object.keys(y).length) &&
 Object.keys(x).reduce(function(isEqual, key) {
     return isEqual && _isEqual(x[key], y[key]);
     }, true) : (x === y);
  }

  function _type(obj) {
    return Object.fromEntries(
     Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => {
        var type;
        switch (true) {
           case Array.isArray(v):
              type = "array";
              break;
           case v === null:
              type = "null";
              break;
        default:
              type = typeof v;
      }
     return [k, type];
  })
 );
}

 this.register = function(id, app) {
   Object.assign(required, _escape("{" + id.trim() + ":" + JSON.stringify(app) + "}"))
 }

 this.check = function(id, app) {
  if(_isEqual(required[id], _type(app))) {
    return app
  } else {
   console.log("JSInterface Error")
   return undefined
  }
}

}
```

The Usage is preety simple ! An example is given below :

```
var i = new JSInterface()

// Registering an interface
i.register("i1", {
 one: "string",
 two: "number"
})

// Declaring
var test = {
 two: 23,
 one: "Hello"
}

// Checking 
console.log(
 i.check("i1", test).one, 
 i.check("i1", test).two
)
```

The Output is :

```
 // => Hello
// => 23
```

If, I try to violate the interface, e.g. :

```
var test {
  two: "23",
  one: "Hello"
}
```

It returns undefined and logs "JSinterface Error" in the console. So, I am quite satisfied with the result, but the real problem comes here, i.e. strictness ! The interfaces are matched stricly, i.e. if one property is missing, it produces the error, but I want to introduce optional props to JSInterface but I am not understanding how to do it ! So, can you suggest me, how can this be done. I will appreciate some examples. I know javascript is a dynamically typed language, but I want to bring some strictness in the way I code in javascript, but in a certain condition, i.e. it should be easy and flexiable to use. E.g. syntax (Probable) :

```
i.register("i2", {
 one: "string",
 two: "number" // These props are required
}, {
 three: "object",
 four: "function" // These props are optional 
})
```

Moreover, is my approach worth it ?

Answer (score 0):

I would have made this a comment, but couldn't put code in.

You're pulling on a string that leads to re-creating an entire type system.  But I've done that too! :)

You can do this literally any way you want, but here's a recommendation for syntax:

```js
i.register("i2", {
 one: "string", // Required
 two: "number" // Required
 "three?": "object", // Optional
 "four?": "function" // Optional
})
```

Seriously though, you're building your own type system.  There's no rules here.

---

If you think you'll be doing more than just required vs optional, you may want to allow objects for defining the properties of your type/model, e.g.:

```js
i.register("i2", {
 one: "string", // Required
 two: "number" // Required
 three: {
   type: "object",
   required: false,
 },
 four: {
   type: "function",
   required: false,
   readonly: true,
 }
})
```

Comment: That's a great idea !